# Graphite: sum all stats that match a pattern?

Tags: graphite, statsd

I'm sending stats to a Graphite server via `statsd`. My stats are fairly fine-grained, and can be easily added by developers. I'd like to roll up all statistics matching a certain pattern (`stats.timers.api.*.200.count`, for example). Is that possible within Graphite?

If not, are there other systems that I should be looking at that can generate that type of roll-up data from `statsd`? Or is this the sort of thing that I should do within my `statsd` configuration directly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you after a blanket sum of all the data that matches, then you can use [1](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.sumSeries) sumSeries.

an example:

```
  sumSeries(stats.timers.api.*.200.count)
```

would give you the total for everything that matches stats.timers.api.*.200.count

You can **group** metrics together via the [2](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.groupByNode) groupByNode.

an example

```
  groupByNode(stats.timers.api.*.*.count,4,"sumSeries")
```

would give you a a sum of all the timers that match stats.timers.api.*, by the 4th column ( in this case return code? )

All the functions are documented at http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/functions.html